# Writing to multiple tables using sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic postgres

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, crud, fastapi, pydantic

First API I've built so bear with me, I currently have a FastAPI that is supposed to save a record of an event and when it happened, as well as a list of people who assisted with each event. Currently, my crud.py "post" command currently only posts to 'test', but I also need it to post names of those who helped to 'whohelped'. I've tried to make 'whohelped.event_token' the foreign key of 'Save_Info.token'. A check on whether my models and schema are correctly made would be greatly appreciated. The main issue is I'm totally lost how to make "post" make changes to both tables at once.

models.py

```
from .database import Base
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, Date, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

class Save_Info(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test'
    token = Column(Integer, primary_key = True, autoincrement = True)
    how = Column(String)
    date = Column(Date)
    children = relationship("Who_Helped",back_populates="test")

class Who_Helped(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'whohelped'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True, autoincrement = True)
    event_token = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('test.token'))
    who_helped = Column(String)
```

schema.py

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional, List
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from sqlalchemy import DateTime

class Who_Helped(BaseModel):
    id: int
    event_token: int
    who_helped: Optional[str]

class Save_Info(BaseModel):
    token: int
    how: str
    date: str

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

crud.py

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from . import schema, models


def post_info(db: Session, info: schema.Save_Info):
    device_info_model = models.Save_Info(**info.dict())
    db.add(device_info_model)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(device_info_model)
    return device_info_model

def get_info(db: Session, token: int = None):
    if token is None:
        return db.query(models.Save_Info).all()
    else:
        return db.query(models.Save_Info).filter(models.Save_Info.token == token).first()

def error_message(message):
    return {
        'error': message
    }
```

main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, HTTPException
from .database import SessionLocal, engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from .schema import Save_Info
from . import crud, models

models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

app = FastAPI()

def db():
    try:
        db = SessionLocal()
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

@app.post('/device/info')
def post_info(info: Save_Info, db=Depends(db)):
    object_in_db = crud.get_info(db, info.token)
    if object_in_db:
        raise HTTPException(400, detail= crud.error_message('This account of saving the world already exists'))
    return crud.post_info(db,info)

@app.get('/device/info/{token}')
def get_info(token: int, db=Depends(db)):
    info = crud.get_info(db,token)
    if info:
        return info
    else:
        raise HTTPException(404, crud.error_message('No info found for this account of saving the world {}'.format(token)))

@app.get('/device/info')
def get_all_info(db=Depends(db)):
    return crud.get_info(db)
```

Comment: Create a `WhoHelped` instance in `crud.post_info` and add it to the session.

Comment: @snakecharmerb how do I add another instance to the session?

Comment: can you plz more elaborate for this question